# Why my file mime type has double quotes?

Tags: javascript, mime, filechooser

I'm working on a web application in which users may add files using a classical file chooser.

As all file formats aren't supported, I filter them based upon their mimetypes using the following code :

```
                var fileChooser = $("#fileInputChooser")[0];
                var valid = fileChooser != undefined && fileChooser.files.length > 0
                if(valid) {
                    valid = _.every(fileChooser.files, function(file) {
                        return SupportedMimeTypes[file.type]!=undefined
                    })
                }
```

I've discovered today that sometimes, my PDF file isn't recognised, where it should.

Indeed, my `SupportedMimeTypes` array contains the following

```
{
 text/x-pdf: Object,
 text/pdf: Object,
 applications/vnd.pdf: Object,
 application/pdf: Object,
 application/x-pdf: Object,
 application/acrobat: Object,
 application/vnd.ms-powerpoint: Object,
 application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation: Object,
 application/vnd.ms-excel: Object,
 application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet: Object,
 9 de plus… 
}
```

And the indicated mimetype for that file (as Firefox debugger indicates me) is `""application/pdf""`. Wait ...

**What the hell are those pairs of double quotes ?**
Where do they come from ? Is it a Firefox bug ? *It seems so, since the same JS code works on Chrome.*

Should I use a typical JS fix by stripping those unwanted characters out of my mime type ? Or is it a "cleaner" way ?